# Is it possible to assign a parameter value within handlebars templates without using helpers?

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to assign values within a template, the idea is to do something like this:

```
    {{#if author}}
        {{className = 'classA'}}  <- trying to implement this line.
    {{else}}
        {{className = 'classB'}}
    {{/if}}

<div class={{className}}></div>
```

Is it possible to do so without registerHelper?

Comment: I need more context. What do you want to do with person? Is it a javascript variable?

Comment: I've changed the example, hopefully now it's more clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this with a [partial](https://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html).

partial:

```
<div class="{{classname}}">{{var1.author}}</div>
```

template:

```
{{#if author}}
{{> mypartial var1=. classname="classA"}}
{{else}}
{{> mypartial var1=. classname="classB"}}
{{/if}}
```

In this example I've passed the current scope as var1. I can't recall if the scope stays the same and the new variable is just added to it or if you have to pass the scope manually.

Comment: Handlbars partial documentation can be seen [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html).

Answer (score 28):

I needed this solution solved in the same way the original poster expected. Therefore I created a helper function to do this for me.

```
function setVariable(varName, varValue, options){
  options.data.root[varName] = varValue;
};
```

Contained within the options in the helper, is the data block, with the root of the helper variables.

I placed my variable within the root object, either assigning or overwriting with the value provided.

The helper in html looks a lot like this.

```
{{setVariable "thisVar" "Contents Here"}}

<div>
  {{thisVar}}
</div>
```

Comment: it is also printing the variable. ? how to get rid of that?

Comment: btw, now in Handlebars 4.x, it seems you have to do `{{@root.thisVar}}` and make sure the `options.data.root` is an object.

Comment: YoYo ... remove the div from the template

Comment: How the heck is this not baked into Handlebars to begin with?

Comment: Are there any security implications (potential vulnerabilities) with adding this helper if you allow users to create arbitrary templates?

Comment: OP requested being able to do this without registering a helper. This answer works, but is not what was asked for.

Answer (score 18):

Small update from a helpful above answer. In Handlebars 4.x, it seems we have to get the variables from @root.

```
handlebars.registerHelper('assign', function (varName, varValue, options) {
    if (!options.data.root) {
        options.data.root = {};
    }
    options.data.root[varName] = varValue;
});
```

And then,

```
{{assign 'imageTag' 'drop-155'}}

{{@root.imageTag}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 {{#if author}}
       <div class='{{ classA }}'></div>
    {{else}}
        <div class='{{ classB }}'></div>
    {{/if}}
```

or try

```
<div class='{{#if author}} {{ classA }} {{else}} {{ classB }} {{/if}}'></div>
```

or maybe this

create a script

```
<script> 
  $(function(){
       var class;
       {{#if author}}
          class = {{ classA }}
       {{else}}
          class = {{ classB }}
       {{/if}}

   var $specials = $('.special');
   $specials.removeClass('special');
   $specials.addClass(class);
  })

</script>
```

Comment: This solution is not so good for me, I need to use this param in several places. I was hoping for a more elegant solution.