# set variables in handlebars root with hadlebars dot net

Tags: c#, handlebars.net

I need to create some variables to use them in diferent customs handlebars helpers.

Looking  how to do it i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50427569/3306955) answer, in which this code is used:

```
handlebars.registerHelper('assign', function (varName, varValue, options) {
    if (!options.data.root) {
        options.data.root = {};
    }
    options.data.root[varName] = varValue;
});
```

That is Javascript code, i need to do the same in C#, in which I don't see how to access to the "root" object.

has someone done something like that before? how should i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I found that the context parameter in the Handlebars `RegisterHelper` Function is a `JObject`, so i used the method `Add` of `JObject` and added the properties needed and simply used them in the template like they were part of the data passed to the template

Comment: Do you have example how you did this?

Comment: I don't have access to the code (I'm Working in a different company now) but I can create a code example at the end of the day